# How to write an update trigger on a foreign key table so that it also considers updates on primary key table?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables as follows:

[image]

I need to write an update trigger on Cities table. It should insert a new entry in an Audit table in either of the following cases:

1) Record in Cities table is updated

2) Record in Countries table, corresponding to the foreign key CountryID in Cities table, is updated

Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: You have to write separate triggers. Each trigger is fired by exactly one table and up to three actions on that table.

Comment: Thank you. I am making this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following comment is the answer:

//You have to write separate triggers. Each trigger is fired by exactly one table and up to three actions on that table. – Damien_The_Unbeliever//